# Reverse of JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm stringyfing an object like `{'foo': 'bar'}`

How can I turn the string back to an object?

Comment: Note that `{foo: 'bar'}` isn't valid JSON (while it is a valid javascript expression).

Comment: simply try JSON.parse. if your browser have no support then try json2.js

Comment: guys we're dealing with a lolcat here.

Comment: Maybe I should have added another (read fourth) answer saying you should do JSON.parse...

Comment: @RobW, turns out that your google link points back to this question as the top hit. #ironic

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - yea, after 5 months of Google looking at it! ;D

Answer (score 683, accepted):

You need to [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) your valid JSON string.

```js
var str = '{"hello":"world"}';
try {
  var obj = JSON.parse(str); // this is how you parse a string into JSON 
  document.body.innerHTML += obj.hello;
} catch (ex) {
  console.error(ex);
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: always put JSON.parse() into try-catch structures, as the method can crash your Node/Js

Comment: Beware: JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( {one:1} )) will bite.

Answer (score 102):

`JSON.parse` is the opposite of `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 89):

`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are almost oposites, and "usually" this kind of thing will work:

```
var obj = ...;
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);  
var obj2 = JSON.parse(json);
```

so that obj and obj2 are "the same".

However there are some limitations to be aware of.
Often these issues dont matter as you're dealing with simple objects.
But I'll illustrate some of them here, using this helper function:

```
function jsonrepack( obj ) { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj) ); }
```

- You'll only get `ownProperties` of the object and lose prototypes:

  ```
  var MyClass = function() { this.foo="foo"; } 
  MyClass.prototype = { bar:"bar" }

  var o = new MyClass();
  var oo = jsonrepack(o);
  console.log(oo.bar); // undefined
  console.log( oo instanceof MyClass ); // false
  ```
- You'll lose identity:

  ```
  var o = {};
  var oo = jsonrepack(o);
  console.log( o === oo ); // false
  ```
- Functions dont survive:

  ```
  jsonrepack( { f:function(){} } ); // Returns {}
  ```
- Date objects end up as strings:

  ```
  jsonrepack(new Date(1990,2,1)); // Returns '1990-02-01T16:00:00.000Z'
  ```
- Undefined values dont survive:

  ```
  var v = { x:undefined }
  console.log("x" in v);              // true
  console.log("x" in jsonrepack(v));  // false
  ```
- Objects that provide a `toJSON` function may not behave correctly.

  ```
  x = { f:"foo", toJSON:function(){ return "EGAD"; } }
  jsonrepack(x) // Returns 'EGAD'
  ```

I'm sure there are issues with other built-in-types too. (All this was tested using node.js so you may get slightly different behaviour depending on your environment too).

When it does matter it can sometimes be overcome using the additional parameters of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`. For example:

```
function MyClass (v) {
   this.date = new Date(v.year,1,1);
   this.name = "an object";
};

MyClass.prototype.dance = function() {console.log("I'm dancing"); }

var o = new MyClass({year:2010});
var s = JSON.stringify(o);

// Smart unpack function
var o2 = JSON.parse( s, function(k,v){
  if(k==="") { 
     var rv = new MyClass(1990,0,0);
     rv.date = v.date;
     rv.name = v.name;
     return rv
  } else if(k==="date") {
    return new Date( Date.parse(v) );
  } else { return v; } } );

console.log(o);             // { date: <Mon Feb 01 2010 ...>, name: 'an object' }
console.log(o.constructor); // [Function: MyClass]
o.dance();                  // I'm dancing

console.log(o2);            // { date: <Mon Feb 01 2010 ...>, name: 'an object' }
console.log(o2.constructor) // [Function: MyClass]        
o2.dance();                 // I'm dancing
```

Comment: Per the [`JSON SPEC`](http://json.org/) *"JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others."*. To me this says that JSON should only be used for language agnostic types/data. Therefore, your example (while very valid) only relates to JSON in it's association to JavaScript, and should be more-so defined as JSONP, and not true JSON... IMO

Comment: One example of this is that `{ bar:"bar" }` (from your prototype) is [not considered valid json](http://jsonlint.com/) since `foo` is a variable rather than a string. Valid json needs the `key` to be a `string`.

Comment: I read the OP as saying "I converted a javascript object to a JSON string, and now I want to convert it back - how do I do it?" All the other answers say just use `JSON.parse`. I'm just warning that theres a lot of cases that will not handle correctly. If you're using pure primitive data (no classes, prototypes) and only the datatypes supported by JSON (no dates, XML, HTML etc. ) then you're OK.

Comment: Also in Javascript `X = { foo:"bar" }` is the same as `X = { "foo":"bar" }` which is the same as `X = {}; X.foo = "bar"` which is the same as `X={}; X["foo"] = "bar"` The resulting object is identical in all 4 cases. That makes no difference to the validity of the generated JSON.

Comment: This is an outstandingly comprehensive answer, and far more worthy of being the accepted answer. Thank you for your excellent work.

Comment: neither `jsonrepack(new Date(1,2,1990));` nor `jsonrepack(new Date(1990,2,1));` returns `'1990-02-01T16:00:00.000Z'` for me, but `'1906-08-10T22:00:00.000Z'` and `'1990-02-28T23:00:00.000Z'` :P

Comment: @MA-Maddin you're right that it should be `jsonrepack(new Date(1990,2,1));` and I've corrected that. The reason you see a difference in the output for that case is the timezone you're using is different to mine - and `new Date(1990,2,1)` is the date for 1 Feb 1990 in the UTC timezone.

Comment: Great answer - thorough and beautifully QED.  It also alerted me to a specific bump in the road that I was sure to hit.  Thanks for going the extra mile.

Answer (score 8):

Recommended is to use `JSON.parse`

There is an alternative you can do :

```
 var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

[Json in javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html)

[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 8):

http://jsbin.com/tidob/1/edit?js,console,output

The native JSON object includes two key methods.

```
1. JSON.parse()
2. JSON.stringify()
```

1. The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string - i.e. reconstructing the original JavaScript object

   `var jsObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);`
2. JSON.stringify() method accepts a JavaScript object and returns its JSON equivalent.

   `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsObject);`

Answer (score 6):

How about this

```
var parsed = new Function('return ' + stringifiedJSON )();
```

This is a safer alternative for `eval`.

```js
var stringifiedJSON = '{"hello":"world"}';
var parsed = new Function('return ' + stringifiedJSON)();
alert(parsed.hello);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this out.
http://jsfiddle.net/LD55x/

Code:

```
var myobj = {};
myobj.name="javascriptisawesome";
myobj.age=25;
myobj.mobile=123456789;
debugger;
var str = JSON.stringify(myobj);
alert(str);
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
alert(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this partial solution?

I wanna store (using a Config node) a global bigobj, with data + methods (as an alternative to importing an external library), used in many function nodes on my flow:

Strange but it works:
The global variable 'bigobj':

```
{
some[]more[]{dx:"here"} , // array of objects with  array of objects. The 'Config' node requires JSON.
.....
 "get_dx": "function( d,p) {  return this.some[d].more[p].dx; }"  // test function
}
```

i.e. a JSON version of a function.... (all in one line :( )

USE:
Inside a function node:

```
var bigO = global.get("bigobj");

function callJSONMethod(obj, fname, a, b, c, d){
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125059/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-eval-based-function-injavascript
var wrap = s => "{ return " + obj[fname] + " };" //return the block having function expression
var func = new Function(wrap(obj[fname]));
return func.call( null ).call( obj, a, b, c, d); //invoke the function using arguments
}

msg.payload =callJSONMethod(bigO, "get_dx", 2, 2); 
return msg:
```

returns "here", unbelieve!

i.e I must add the function callJSONMethod() to any function block using bigobj.....
maybe acceptable.

Best regards