# Regex to Extract Props + Values from String that contains a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a React component, but the raw string:

```js
<MyComponent id={123} value={345} name="Thomas" />
```

How can I regex through this string and extract all props & their value?

```js
{
  id: 123,
  value: 345,
  name: "Thomas"
}
```

I am struggling to understand how to go about something like this.

I've tried things like this, but they aren't really getting me anywhere... :

```js
let res = myComp.match(/.*<MyComponent id={.*/g)
let value = res[0].split('{')[1].split('}')[0]
```

Comment: If you are receiving that object as a string, you can use JSON.parse() to convert it into an object. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171746/reverse-of-json-stringify

Comment: If the component is all there is to the string, you could just match the content of what looks like properties by using lookarounds to make sure what you match is framed by `={...}` or `="..."`. Something like `(?<=={)[^}]*(?=})|(?<==")[^"]*(?=")` used like `let results = 'component-markup'.match(/expression/g)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be using a pattern with an infinite lookbehind assertion if supported and 3 capture groups with an alternation.

Assuming there are no other occurrences of `<` and `>` in the string:

```
(?<=<MyComponent\s[^<>]*)([^\s=]+)=(?:{([^{}]*)}|"([^"]*)")(?=[^<>]*\/>)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oi3nfU/1);

```js
const regex = /(?<=<MyComponent\s[^<>]*)([^\s=]+)=(?:{([^{}]*)}|"([^"]*)")(?=[^<>]*\/>)/g;
const s = `<MyComponent id={123} value={345} name="Thomas" />`;
const result = {};
Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => {
  result[m[1]] = m[2] ? parseInt(m[2]) : m[3]
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regexp should scan all of the name/value pairs.  You can use this in a matchAll() to return an iterable object with all the matches.  The name is in capture group 1 and the value can be gotten by concatenating groups 3, 4, and 5.  You can add javascript code to iterate this structure and build your result string.

```
/([\w.:-]+)(\s*=\s*)(?:\{(.+?)\}|(".*?")(?<!\\")|(\w+))/gs
```

[image]

I added a little defensive check to handle escaped double-quotes inside double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Given your string, another regex that would retrieve your values is the following:

```
(\b\S+\b)=[{"](\b\S+\b)["}]
```

**Regex Explanation**:

- `(\b\S+\b)`: Group 1, non-space characters sequence
- `=`: =
- `[{"]`: either open brace or double quotes
- `(\b\S+\b)`: Group 2, , non-space characters sequence
- `[}"]`: either closed brace or double quotes

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/NCEH34/1).

```js
let text = "<MyComponent id={123} value={345} name=\"Thomas\" />";

let regex = /(\b\S+\b)=[{"](\b\S+\b)["}]/g;

let results = text.matchAll(regex);

for (result of results) {
  console.log("Key:", result[1], ' Value:', result[2])
}
```